# Div not being styled correctly (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css, styles

https://codio.com/MylesGordon12/PCList/

On test.html, the div "popup" can't be styled for some reason. Help appreciated.

Comment: Please make a small reproducible example, a fiddle for example. No one is going to go to your website and search for what the issue could be.

Comment: Please paste the code into your question. BTW: Your link doesn't work (anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please try to paste your code here... and try doing this change:

```
<div style="popup">
```

change it for

```
<div class="popup">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<div style="popup">
```

with

```
<div class="popup">
```

and then add css for `.popup`